# WSDL service location base URL will be different in each environment and how to not build the same jar over and over again

Tags: soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

I have a wsdl file, which contains service-tag and partial view of it:

```
<service name="EXFlowers">
   <port binding="getflowers:EXFlowersGetflowers" name="EXFlowersGetflowersService">
       <soap:address location="http://dev.example.com:67857/EXFlowers/getflowers" />
   </port>
</service>
```

My problem is in this part:

```
<soap:address location="http://dev.example.com:67857/EXFlowers/getflowers" />
```

I am using [wsdl2java](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) which creates .java files from the wsdl file (*then I compile the generated files and make a jar file out of it for using it in WebSpehere*).

As it is now I can't promote a .jar file from one environment to another (*for example: development -> test -> staging -> production*), because the **location** in each environment has different base url. I hate to run wsdl2java for each environment (*basically create the same jar 5 times with just different string values in some of the class files*). I want "build once, run anywhere" workflow and I found this from IBM's support page https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/accommodating-different-wsdl-urls-between-environments which explains how it could be done.

So my question is:
Can a kindly soul explain me with syntax examples how option 2 can be done:

> 2. Use a file:// based WSDL URL. Store the WSDL file itself in the same file path in each environment, but use different contents with
>    custom hostnames and/or endpoint URLs therein.

I don't understand it, how will it look like:

```
<soap:address location="file://tmp/myendpointfile.txt and what about this part -> /EXFlowers/getflowers" />
```

and how will the content of the file be ?

```
cat /tmp/myendpointfile.txt
http://dev.example.com:67857
```

I would appreciate any help or if you guys know a better way of accomplishing this task.